# Using sum if to calculate total flying hours based on sortie type

Tags: excel, vba

I keep a digital copy of my flying logbook. Each month I calculate hours for the month, total and role specific.

I'm trying to use the sumif function to look for any AAR sorties between each monthly summary and calculate the hourly total.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub monthlyadder(toprow As Integer) 
Dim count As Integer 
Dim thing As Integer 
Dim AAR As String

count = 0 
AAR = Sheets("Templates").Cells(7, 12).Value

Sheets("Logbook").Cells(toprow - 1, 1).Select Do Until ActiveCell = "Monthly"
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
count = count + 1 Loop
'for the top line in the summary, make each column the sum of the months AT achievement
For thing = 9 To 22
    Sheets("Logbook").Cells(toprow, thing) = columnsum(count - 1, thing, toprow - 1, "Page")
Next thing 'for the 3rd and 4th lines = monthly total and Voyager total
For thing = 9 To 22
    Sheets("Logbook").Cells(toprow + 2, thing) = columnsum(count - 1, thing, toprow - 1, "Page")
    Sheets("Logbook").Cells(toprow + 3, thing) = Sheets("Logbook").Cells(toprow + 2, thing) + Sheets("Logbook").Cells(toprow - (2 + count), thing)
Next thing 'for the second line in the summary, make each column the sum of the months AAR achievement
For thing = 9 To 22
    If Sheets("Logbook").Cells("G").Value = AAR And Sheets("Logbook").Cells(columnsum(count - 1, thing, toprow - 1, "Page")) = thing Then
        Sheets("Logbook").Cells(toprow + 1, thing) = columnsum(count - 1, thing, toprow - 1, "Page")
    End If
Next thing
```

The top line and the 3rd and 4th lines return the correct values.

How do I get the 2nd line to return only the AAR sortie values as a sum?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do but I thought I'd show you how to abbreviate your sheet name. The advantage to doing this is that it makes the code a lot easier to read and if you change the sheet name, you don't have to change each reference.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MonthlyAdder(TopRow As Integer)
Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim Sh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim count As Integer
Dim thing As Integer
Dim AAR As String

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Sh = Wb.Sheets("Logbook")

count = 0
AAR = Sheets("Templates").Cells(7, 12).Value

Sh.Cells(TopRow - 1, 1).Select
Do Until ActiveCell = "Monthly"
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    count = count + 1
Loop

'for the top line in the summary, make each column the sum of the months AT achievement
For thing = 9 To 22
    Sh.Cells(TopRow, thing) = columnsum(count - 1, thing, TopRow - 1, "Page")
Next thing 'for the 3rd and 4th lines = monthly total and Voyager total
For thing = 9 To 22
    Sh.Cells(TopRow + 2, thing) = columnsum(count - 1, thing, TopRow - 1, "Page")
    Sh.Cells(TopRow + 3, thing) = Sh.Cells(TopRow + 2, thing) + Sh.Cells(TopRow - (2 + count), thing)
Next thing 'for the second line in the summary, make each column the sum of the months AAR achievement
For thing = 9 To 22
    If Sh.Cells("G").Value = AAR And Sh.Cells(columnsum(count - 1, thing, TopRow - 1, "Page")) = thing Then
    Sh.Cells(TopRow + 1, thing) = columnsum(count - 1, thing, TopRow - 1, "Page")
    End If
Next thing

End Sub
```